# SAS Hash Tables Merge Error --> Key Mismatch

Tags: hash, merge, sas, hashtable

I've been having trouble using hash tables to merge my 2 data sets. The hash table I declared has 1 key and 2 data variables.

```
data final_table;   
 if 0 then set hash_data;
    if _N_=1 then do;
     declare hash hashlookup (dataset:'hash_data');
     hashlookup.definekey('key');
      hashlookup.definedata('ABC', 'XYZ');
     hashlookup.definedone();
     end;
 set datatabletwo;  
 rc = hashlookup.find(key:'key'); 
 run;
```

The key is a numeric variable of the same length. I have already tried to reformat both keys to character, but the log still returns the following error message: `ERROR: Type mismatch for key variable KEY at line 57 column 7.`

Hope someone can help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that this

```
rc = hashlookup.find(key:'key');
```

looks up the string `'key'` and not the value in variable `key`. Therefore, do this instead

```
data final_table;   
 if 0 then set hash_data;
    if _N_=1 then do;
     declare hash hashlookup (dataset:'hash_data');
     hashlookup.definekey('key');
     hashlookup.definedata('ABC', 'XYZ');
     hashlookup.definedone();
     end;
 set datatabletwo;  
 rc = hashlookup.find(); 
 run;
```

Comment: The `find` method without `key:`  parameters will use the PDV variables named in `definekey`.  In this case the variable `key`